# Error in if (abs(myCor[i, j] - 1) < 1e-04) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r

```
vector <- numeric()
for (i in 1:dim(myCor)[1]-1){
   for (j in i+1:dim(myCor)[2]){
      if(abs(myCor[i,j]-1)<0.1){
         vector<-append(vector,j)
      }
   }
}
```

I don't know why this happens. I am a very new learner in R.

Comment: Without a full working example it's hard to say. The error suggests you are subsetting beyond max value of some dimension. Have you tried telling second `for` more explicitly about the vector you're trying to skip along? Something along the lines of `(i+1):dim(myCor)[2]`?

Comment: I was actually finding the collinear vectors in a matrix. I got correlation matrix using myCor<-cor(myMatrix,use="pairwise.complete.obs"). I set the error bound to be 0.1 to check if the correlation is closed to 1(positive correlated).